# Data Manipulation

Tags: dataset, data-preprocessing

I currently have $n$ datapoints along $k$ dimensions ($n$ observations and $k$ variables). I need to drop a lot of these observations by some criteria. To be more specific, I have to perform a few operations of the following type:

1. Drop if for the $k^{th}$ variable, the value of the observations is less than 50.
2. Drop if for the $(k-1^{th})$ variable, the value of the observations is less than 60.

etc. etc.

Does it matter in which order I perform these operations?  Will I end up with exactly the same dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, yes you will. Each of your operations forms a boolean operation, e.g. in your first case $x_k \ge 60$. The remaining data are those that return true for all of these operations.

By the [associative property of logical conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction#Properties), it doesn't matter what order you apply them in.

Some python to demonstrate:

```
def firstFilter(t):
    return t[0] > 20
def secondFilter(t):
    return t[1] > 40
aSetToFilter = zip(range(30), [i + 20 for i in range(30)])
print [i for i in [i for i in aSetToFilter if secondFilter(i)] if firstFilter(i)], [i for i in [i for i in aSetToFilter if firstFilter(i)] if secondFilter(i)]
```

Will output this same list twice:

```
[(21, 41), (22, 42), (23, 43), (24, 44), (25, 45), (26, 46), (27, 47), (28, 48), (29, 49)]
```